# C++ using System.Drawing namespace

Tags: c++-cli, system.drawing

I'm quite a newbee in working with images. I need to use System.Drawing namespace and when i try to do it like this: `using namespace System::Drawing;` i have an error that System hasn't been declared. What should i do? Include somthing?

Comment: It smells like you forgot to add the reference.  But since it does not like System either you probably used the wrong project template to get started.  You have to pick one from the CLR node.  Most anything that System::Drawing can do is also available in native code by #including gdiplus.h

Answer (score 3):

You need `#using <System.Drawing.dll>` and of course it have to be CLR project.